# What's the most efficient way to delete the rest of the line in Terminal?

Tags: command-line, terminal, command-line-interface

If I'm running the command:

```
vim app/views/posts/new.html.slim
```

and my cursor is on the `n` character (in the word new).

What's the quickest way to delete the `n` and all of the characters that follow it?

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/a/269048/475597

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> does this, at least in Ubuntu and OS X.

Comment: awesome - thanks. I can accept this as an answer in 5 minutes :)